# TableView reloadData not reloading?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, reloaddata

First I initialize the table with initWithCoder and then load the data in the cell. When data source changes (which is web service) I want table to reload. Just for testing I hooked up button action and added `[self.tableView reloadData]`

However table doesn't reload but the data source has been changed. If I go to different view and come back to table view new data is shown. Any suggestions?

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.titleList = [[SearchModel alloc] init];
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
        [self.titleList load: ^(id json) {
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        }];
    }
    return self;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"title";
    TitleDetailCell *cell = nil;
    Model *title = nil;

     title = [self.titleList get:indexPath.row];

    if (cell == NULL)

    {
        cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


        [cell movieTitleLabel].text = [title get:@"title"];
        [[cell movieImageView] setImageWithURL: thumbnail];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: why you set table delegate and datasource in cellForRowAtIndexPath method? it will never get called if data source was not set up in the first place

Comment: Where should I set it? I tried placing it in viewDidApper

Comment: anywhere before you reload data. viewDidLoad: is the usual place for that. Or if you use IB - it is better to setup delegate and data source there

Answer (score 0):

At the time `initWithCoder:` is called the `tableView` has not been created yet.

Move the code from `initWithCoder:` to `viewDidAppeare:`, reload data on the main thread, it should help:

```
self.titleList = [[SearchModel alloc] init];
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
        [self.titleList load: ^(id json) {
            // Log data to see is data is ready
             NSLog(@"%@",[title get:@"title"]);
            // Reload table on the main thread
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.tableView reloadData];
                [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
            });
        }];
```

Comment: Nothing loads in that case. I guess data for table needs to be ready before view appears. So I placed the code to viewWillApper but nothing reloads.

Comment: Yes, The data needs to be ready before you call reloadData. Load the data in viewDidAppeare, log it to make sure the data is ready and reload the table view. If the log shows that you are missing the data your problem is in SearchModel class.

Comment: I placed the code in viewDidApper and data loads fine. However reload still doesn't work.

Comment: @JamesDouglas reload table on the main thread, see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You don't do anything with the data that arrives in the callback (`json`). Do you need to store it anywhere so you can display in the table view?
2. Does the callback happen on the main thread or a background thread? If you're doing UI stuff you need to make sure it's on the main thread

Comment: Data is stored in the @property (nonatomic, strong) SearchModel *titleList; 

What do you mean by callback. Data source doesn't change on the main thread it changes on the model class, the one I call from the initWithCoder. I know when the data is changed so I am calling reload table.

Comment: You mean the model loads data into itself? By callback I mean the block you pass in to `load:`. You seem to be conflating classes and threads in that comment?

Comment: No. That is instance of Model class.

Model class gets the data from web service and returns the data. Model class is called in initWithCoder. 

I am beginner can please clarify what do you mean by main thread and how should I know if data is loaded on the main thread. Thanks